# What are the steps needed to set up SSH on ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: ssh

What are the steps needed to set up SSH on ubuntu 16.04?

Step 1) I generated my keys on my windows box with puttygen.

Step 2) I logged into my server

Step 3) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to install the ssh server.

`sudo apt install openssh-server`

Then, if you wish to only use key-based logins, follow the procedure in the [wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/OpenSSH/Keys) here to transfer the keys.

Comment: +1; still you forgot to put it as step 4) ... and most obviously there should be step 5) PROFIT!!! (*kidding*)

Comment: Doh! (hangs head in shame)

Comment: @ Thanks!  Installing openssh and generating the key(s) is no problem.  But I read the wiki and I don't see any good way to get the key off my Ubuntu box and onto my windows machine at home.  How do I find that file and do that?

Comment: http://bodhizazen.com/Tutorials/SSH_overview and http://bodhizazen.com/Tutorials/SSH_keys#Transfer . You can transfer the key with winscp https://winscp.net/eng/download.php

Comment: @DR01D You actually need to move your client key (windows machine) to the SSH server, not the other way.  A USB thumb drive will work fine for that.

Comment: @organicMarble  My windows machine is in Arizona.  My server is in San Francisco.  This is mindboggling, haha.

Comment: In that case, other means will be necessary :) @Panther has mentioned one in a comment.  Or you can just transfer the file electronically.